# xcode 7 beta stuck at "Running xxxxx WatchKit App on iPhone 6"

Tags: xcode7, watchos-2

I recently tried to build new watch os 2 watch app. However, my Xcode 7 beta is not working. I tried reinstalled already. It still doesn't work. It basically stuck at "Running xxxxx WatchKit App on iPhone 6" every time I tried to run it on the watch and iPhone simulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the watch app in the iPhone setting